# Grouping properties using JAXB annotations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, oxm

I have a class `Product` with the following properties: `name`, `dateCreated`, `createdByUser`, `dateModified` and `modifiedByUser`, and I'm using JAXB marshalling. I'd like to have output like this:

```
<product>
    <name>...</name>
    <auditInfo>
        <dateCreated>...</dateCreated>
        <createdByUser>...</createdByUser>
        <dateModified>...</dateModified>
        <modifiedByUser>...</modifiedByUser>
    </auditInfo>
</product>
```

but ideally I'd like to avoid having to create a separate `AuditInfo` wrapper class around these properties.

Is there a way to do this with JAXB annotations? I looked at `@XmlElementWrapper` but that's for collections only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't believe so.  The intermediary class is necessary.

You can weasel your way around this by having `AuditInfo` as a nested inner class within `Product`, and add getter and setter methods to `Product` which set the fields on the `AuditInfo`. Clients of `Product` need never know.

```
public class Product {
   private @XmlElement AuditInfo auditInfo = new AuditInfo();

   public void setDateCreated(...) {
      auditInfo.dateCreated = ...
   }

   public static class AuditInfo {
      private @XmlElement String dateCreated;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB 2.X ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

You can use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension for this use case:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Product {

    private String name;

    @XmlPath("auditInfo/dateCreated/text()")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @XmlPath("auditInfo/createdByUser/text()")
    private String createdByUser;
}
```

**For More Information:**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: This looks like a useful extension. Thanks for the info.